# Outputting a value with two decimals using "double"

Tags: c++, double

I'm working on a program that outputs the total amount of money spent on gasoline based a value that the user inputs. I want it to output a value with 2 decimals, but the program rounds whatever the total is instead of outputting what the total should be. I am a beginner and have no idea why it isn't working correctly.

```
double gasPrice = 3.87;
double gallonsPumped = 0;



cout<<"How many gallons of gasoline (Diesel) were purchased today:"<<endl;
cin>>gallonsPumped;
int finalGasPrice = gasPrice*gallonsPumped;

cout<<endl;

if (gallonsPumped >= 1)
{
    cout<<endl<<"The total cost for gasoline today was $"<<finalGasPrice<<"."<<endl;
}
else
{
    cout<<"No money spent on gasoline today.";
}
```

Comment: try `double finalGasPrice = gasPrice*gallonsPumped;`

Answer (score 4):

An int type is an integer - i.e. no decimal place, so the multiplication is rounded down to the nearest integer.

You want to use a float or double:
`double finalGasPrice = gasPrice*gallonsPumped;`

To get the output format to show exactly two digits after the decimal place, you probably want to use something like:
`cout << setiosflags(ios::fixed) << setprecision(2) << finalGasPrice;`

Comment: You can simply use `std::cout << std::fixed << ...` (rather than `setiosflags(ios::fixed)`....

Answer (score 1):

An integer can only hold whole numbers: no decimals, or fractions. So when you are setting finalgasprice, the result is truncated to an integer.
Initializing finalgasprice as a double will solve this issue.
You should also change '>= 1' to '>= 0', unless you are wanting payments less than a dollar to go unnoticed.